# Terraform Cloud Run Not Recognizing Environment Variables from Variable Set

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-cloud

Here's the situation: I have several environment variables that were previously set as workspace-specific variables. These variables worked as expected when they were defined directly in the workspace. However, I recently decided to consolidate these into a global variable set at the organization level to streamline management.

I followed the steps to create the variable set and added all necessary environment variables. After that, I associated this variable set with the required workspaces.

However, when I trigger a run, the environment variables from the global variable set don't seem to be available or recognized. The Terraform Cloud run behaves as if these variables were never set, even though they're clearly present in the variable set.

Here's what I have already checked:

- The variable set is linked to the correct workspace.
- The environment variables are correctly named, and their values are set as expected in the variable set.
- The Terraform code refers to the environment variables using the correct var syntax.
- Given that these environment variables worked correctly when they were set directly in the workspace, I'm not sure why they aren't working now when set in a global variable set.

Has anyone encountered this issue, and is there a way to resolve it? Why would the Terraform Cloud run not recognize the environment variables from the newly created variable set? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some images:
[image: Error on Run]
[image: Variable set]

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the variables need to be Terraform variables and should not be environment variables!

[image]

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. Still not working.

Comment: My mistake was that I declared ARM-variables in variables.tf which oddly worked before. Now, I deleted them and added the new variables as env variables - It works.